# Pausing threads and manipulating array

Tags: java, multithreading, input, thread-safety

I am building a Tetris game that updates a JPanel of icons in an array.

When a piece is spawned, a new thread is created that moves the piece down the board until a collision. Once the piece collides the thread is stopped and a new one is created in its place with a new piece.

I also have keyboard input that is waited for by a keylistener to move, rotate, and slam the piece down to the bottom of the game grid.

When I go to slam the piece down, execution is passed from the keylistener to the function that handles slamming the piece down. What can occasionally happen is that after I slam the piece down, the game loop crashes and does not start a next piece cycle, so I am left just controlling this piece that is at the bottom of the board.

I tried interrupting the thread then restarting, I tried sleeping the thread but that only halted the issue. I also imagine that part of the issue could be that the array of icons is not thread-safe? Would using a vector resolve the issue?

Is there a proper way I should be doing this?
What I want to do is listen for keyboard input, and when the keyboard input is read, finish the current cycle of the game loop, stop the game loop thread until the keyboard listener function is finished, then restart the game loop where it left off.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Using explicit threads - and particularly one thread per piece - sounds wildly inappropriate.

Comment: Show us what you tried and what doesn't work as expected